# Consolidate duplicated variables while preserving unique values in new columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a moderate dataset of tag return data where individuals are differentiated with a unique tag number (TagNo). Some of these individuals have been recaptured multiple times, but the way our data is reported each recapture instance ends up as an individual row. The code below should reproduce the first ten rows of my dataset. I would like to end up with one row for each TagNo with new columns for each occurrence of recap_date (e.g. recap_date, recap_date_2, recap_date_3, etc) where recap_date is the earliest date, recap_date_2 would be the next chronological date and so on. I would like something similar with TL.y, LAT, and LONG except that these values need to correspond to the correct recap_date (e.g. if recap_date of "2013-06-28" is recap_date_2 for a given TagNo; TL.y_2, LAT_2, and LONG_2 need to be the TL.y, LAT, and LONG that correspond to that recap_date for that TagNo). Obviously an individual that has been recaptured twice will not have values for recap_date_3 and NA is an acceptable value in that instance.

I've tried things like `pivot_wider()` and other long to wide conversions, but to my understanding my data is already mostly wide. I've also search SO pretty extensively and haven't been able to find a solution. Admittedly, that could be due to operator error in my search methods! I feel like a `for` loop could be a solution, but I am not knowledgeable enough on that front to figure it out and most examples are for exceedingly simple problems. Any help would be appreciated. And hopefully it's clear what I am looking for!

```
 structure(list(TagNo = c("EC50249", "EC50249", "EC50249", "EC50249", 
"EC52114", "EC52114", "EC52411", "EC52411", "EC60203", "EC60203"
), Species = c("Red grouper", "Red grouper", "Red grouper", "Red grouper", 
"Red grouper", "Red grouper", "Red grouper", "Red grouper", "Red grouper", 
"Red grouper"), TL.y = c(11.5, 16, 14, 15, 16, 17, NA, 15, 17, 
12), YR = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L), recap_date = c("2013-04-20", "2013-06-28", 
"2014-04-06", "2014-04-12", "2016-04-12", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-06", 
"2017-01-20", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-12"), LAT = c("24 42", "24 42", 
"24 41", "24 43", "26 05", "26 05", "24 39", "24 39", "26 05", 
"26 05"), LONG = c("80 53", "80 53", "80 58", "80 54", "80 05", 
"80 05", "81 01", "81 02", "80 05", "80 05")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Not so clear, but you can manage it with tidyverse:

```
# some libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 


# your data
df %>%
# make date as date
  mutate(recap_date = as.Date(recap_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
# sort by TagNo and date
  arrange(TagNo, recap_date) %>%
# group by tag no to...
  group_by(TagNo) %>%
# ... add by group an id that is going to be helpful to...
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
# ...make your data wider
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, 
              values_from = c(recap_date, TL.y, YR, LAT, LONG))

 # A tibble: 4 x 22
# Groups:   TagNo [4]
  TagNo Species recap_date_1 recap_date_2 recap_date_3 recap_date_4 TL.y_1 TL.y_2 TL.y_3 TL.y_4  YR_1  YR_2  YR_3  YR_4 LAT_1
  <chr> <chr>   <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1 EC50~ Red gr~ 2013-04-20   2013-06-28   2014-04-06   2014-04-12     11.5     16     14     15  2013  2013  2013  2013 24 42
2 EC52~ Red gr~ 2016-04-12   2016-05-04   NA           NA             16       17     NA     NA  2016  2016    NA    NA 26 05
3 EC52~ Red gr~ 2016-05-06   2017-01-20   NA           NA             NA       15     NA     NA  2016  2016    NA    NA 24 39
4 EC60~ Red gr~ 2016-04-04   2016-04-12   NA           NA             17       12     NA     NA  2016  2016    NA    NA 26 05
# ... with 7 more variables: LAT_2 <chr>, LAT_3 <chr>, LAT_4 <chr>, LONG_1 <chr>, LONG_2 <chr>, LONG_3 <chr>, LONG_4 <chr>
```

Comment: This got me 99% of the way there. Somehow I still ended up with multiple rows of the same TagNo, but with the recap_date, TL.y, LAT, and LONG values all in the right place (e.g. the second occurrence of the first TagNo had recap_date_1 = NA, recap_date_2 = date and so on). Thankfully that's an issue I know how to fix, so thank you so much. I've been wrestling with this dumb problem for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I think:

```r
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

dlply( x, "TagNo", function(d) {
    cols <- setdiff( colnames(d), c("TagNo","Species") )
    l <- lapply( 1:nrow(d), function(i) {
        r <- d[i,cols]
        if( i > 1 ) {
            names(r) <- paste0( names(r), "_", i )
        }
        r
    })
    do.call( cbind, l )
}) %>% rbindlist(fill=TRUE)
```

You were on the right track. This solution iterates over TagNo's, breaks the sub data.frame up into a list with each element as one of the rows. These are then cbind'ed to create a wide data.frame. All these resulting data.frames are then rbind'ed

Comment: Thanks for the help! For some reason I ended up duplicating every column 9x (the highest number of recaptures for on individual) with this solution. I'm guessing that has a lot more to do with my lack of familiarity w/ `data.table` and `plyr` than your solution! I marked s_'s solution as correct because it worked for me, but I think this could have also if I spent a little more time with it! So thanks again (I've been banging my head against this problem for at least a week).